# ¿Cuál es el origen de "juan" como sinónimo de soldado?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, historia, hispanoamérica, origen

En uno de mis viajes al Diccionario de la lengua, me encuentro que además de usarse como nombre de persona (Juan) también existe el sustantivo **juan** (en minúscula, ya que en este caso de trata de un nombre común):

> 1. m. *Méx.* **soldado** (‖ hombre que sirve en la milicia).

Me llama mucho la atención que juan pueda ser sinónimo de soldado, y por eso me pregunto: ¿alguien sabría decir cuál es su origen?

Comment: Yo apostaría a que el significado procede, simplemente, de que Juan era un nombre muy común y muchos soldados se llamarían así. También en inglés se usa *joe* para referirse a una persona cualquiera, y en algunos ámbitos se usa *john* para referirse a alguien. Pero no es más que mi intución, así que prefiero dejar esto como comentario y no respuesta.

Comment: Más o menos yo también pienso eso, pero como tú, sin ninguna base cierta.

Answer (score 2):

**Cuestión:** ¿Cuál es el origen de "juan" como sinónimo de soldado?

Después del articulo "Juan Soldado" y el comentario de *karloswitt*, trate de investigar un poco y traer a la luz nuevos datos que no tuvieran nada que ver con aquel "Juan Soldado" Mexicano, canonizado como santo.

---

[image]

*Portada Juan Soldado*

*Cuento Ilustrado Editado en México por A Vanegas 1890*

---

https://aguascalientes.gob.mx/temas/cultura/editorial/pdflibros/Juan%20soldado.pdf

---

La leyenda de San Juan, el más joven de los apóstoles, como soldado de Cristo, viene de lejos. La figura del Rey, "Cristo" y el soldado "Juan", es utilizada como símil en muchos sermones.

---

Empero en el mito, el nombre de "Juan" ha sido utilizado desde siempre en la cultura popular junto a otros como Pedro, Antonio..., para expresar cosas parecidas en refranes, dichos y chistes, que servían de aviso, consejo, crítica ó burla hacia algo o alguien.

- " Duerme Juan y yace, que tu asno pace ".
- " Otra al dicho de Juan de Coca ".

---

Juan Soldado, de origen Español, será uno de esos personajes de ficción a modo de Pedro de Urdemalas, Urdemales, Urdimalas, Ordiman, Ardimales, Animala, Pedro Malasarte, conocido durante mucho tiempo y hoy tristemente olvidado.

Así, Juan Soldado fue por excelencia un personaje folclórico producto de la tradición oral y escrita. Aparece en cuentos y narraciones populares diseminados por toda la geografía, representando en su hacer, distintos papeles o aventuras y a veces utilizado como pseudónimo. Igualmente su fama se expandió y formó parte de la tradición de algunos países de Iberoamericana con igual o distinto nombre.

---

[image]

*Nueva Relación de las Dichas y Desdichas de Juan Soldado: esto es, la agudeza de unos en reclutar á otros, el ejercicio, la guardia, el racho y el cuartel, compuesto por un soldado de las guardias Españolas*.

*Publicación Fechada entre 1700 y 1850*.

---

La tradición de "Juan Soldado" es mucho más amplia de lo esperado y recoge distintas etapas anteriores, incluso en la Guerra de Independencia, donde su figura en el imaginario sirvió como personaje inspirador en la lucha contra los Franceses. En este apartado solo se recogen algunas de esas fábulas y variantes del nombre "Juan" que ayuden a entender su sentido, pues como figura popular seria necesario un libro completo dedicado a lo que fue el fenómeno.

---

[image]

*Nuevo y curioso romance en que se explica una breve discrección de lo que pasó Juan Soldado con un chistoso lance*.

*Obra Fechada entre 1819 y 1900, Valladolid*.

---

[image]

*Diccionario Militar Español de 1869*

---

El nombre de "Juan" es la encarnación versátil que sirve para designar características a veces picarescas, ufanas, burlescas, galantes, valientes, militares, románticas, amorosas .... peculiaridades siempre, de alguien en un momento, que enlazan con la representación mental de un nombre común que sirve por antonomasia para designar a todos, aunque todos no posean tales peculiaridades.

- Juan Tonto
- Juan Soldado
- Juan Miseria
- Juan Ceniza...

Como se ha comentado antes, el nombre de "Juan Soldado" ha sido utilizado como pseudónimo por algunos autores literarios, militares... y de cuyo alcance en fama y notoriedad de otros tiempos apenas queda en la memoria actual colectiva. Uno de esos autores fue, el también afamado en su tiempo, Antonio Joaquín Afán de Ribera 1834-1906, que utilizó "Juan Soldado" como pseudónimo en muchas de sus obras.

---

---

Publicación  "Juan Soldado" de 1852;

> «*Juan Soldado. Cuento popular andaluz recogido por Fernán Caballero*»
>
> Autor: Cecilia Böhl de Faber - (Bohl de Faber, Cecilia)
>
> Fernán Caballero fue el seudónimo bajo el que se ocultó la «figura
> inquietante y alusiva», en palabras de José Fer­nández Montesinos, de
> Cecilia Böhl de Faber (Morgues, Suiza, 1796 - Sevilla, 1877).
>
> Temas, motivos y tipos:   Joven sin miedo. Objeto/s mágico/s. Muerto
> viviente. Diablo. Salvación de un alma.
>
> Revistas: Semanario Pintoresco Español, -, 7 (17 de febrero de 1852),
> pp. 53-55.
>
> *Juan Soldado, tras haber servido al rey durante seis años, es despedido y solo recibe un trozo de pan y seis maravedíes por el
> trabajo prestado....*

http://gicesxix.uab.es/showCuento.php?idCuento=183

[image]

Recogido en el Catálogo de Cuentos Folclóricos

---

> JUAN SOLDADO
> Carlos Alba Cellero
> PREMIO FETÉN 2015 A LA MEJOR
> ADAPTACIÓN DEL TEXTO La versión: simbología y riqueza lingüística
>
> Se basa mayormente en el cuento de Fernán Caballero (sobrenombre de la
> escritora andaluza Cecilia Böhl de Faber) y la película de Fernando
> Fernán Gómez. Ambos se inspiraron, a su vez, en la leyenda popular
> “Juan sin miedo”.
>
> "Juan sin miedo".  Cuento de Jacob Grimm y Wilhelm Grimm Fecha de
> publicación original: 20 de diciembre de 1812.

**RECOPILACION DE ALGUNOS "JUANES" TRADICIONALES**

---

Aquí he intentado resumir algunas locuciones, una serie de expresiones referidas concretamente al nombre de "Juan", y que atañen no solo a su condición, sino a la evolución de los nuevos apodos que aparecen acompañando a "Juan" y que en palabras de algún autor antiguo, ese cambio se produciría cada diez años, algo que no ha sido cumplido.

- Juan Diaz como candado ó cerradura.
- Juan Dorado como moneda de oro
- Juan Machir referido al Machete.
- Juan Tarefe referido al dado de jugar.
- Hacer San Juan frase fam. Despedirse los mozos asalariados antes de  cumplir el tiempo de ajuste.
- Juan (en voz alta), para indicar que hay alguien más en la sala.

---

- Juan Un buen Juan, con el que se explica el genio dócil y fácil de engañar.
- Juan expr. que se aplica al hombre sencillo y fácil de engañar.
- Juan de Buen Alma. Buen Juan
- Juan Pelanas Persona de poca importancia ó valía, inútil y despreciable. Perico el de los palotes
- Juan Lanas expr. que se aplica al hombre de genio apocado, que se presta con facilidad a todo cuanto se quiere hacer de él.
- Juan Palomo fam. El hombre que no se vale de nadie. También, el hombre que no sirve para nada.
- **Juan Soldado  Como soldado raso**.

---

- Juan Juanillo / o Juan o Juanillo
- Juan Nadie expr. para alguien desconocido, que no es nadie ó que su nombre no representa nada. Un fulano.
- Juan Panadero. Alberti, lo relaciona con Juan Soldado, Juan sin Miedo. México marioneta tradicional.

> Juan Panadero en la guerra

> fue tan solo un Juan soldado,

> un Juan soldado cualquiera
>
> Que soy yo Juan Panadero,

> lo mismo que Juan o Antonio
>
> Alberti

Otros

(Juan el Oso, Juanillo el Valiente, Juan de la Valmuza, Juan Vaquero)

---

[image]

[image]

*Cuentos tradicionales e Índice de una edición de 1926*

---

En las algunas de las distintas expresiones referidas a "Juan", éste aparece con rasgos que se dirigen hacia alguien sumiso, dócil, alguien fácil de engañar y que se presta con facilidad a todo cuanto se quiere hacer de él, es decir, como suelen hacer con los reclutas cuando llegan al cuartel, al igual que queda reflejado en alguna de estas obras.

En este sentido es curioso, sobre todo, que se utilicen los términos "Pelanas y Lanas" para referirse concretamente a esos trazos del carácter y al aspecto más llano ó bajo de alguien, que como los mozos reclutas, tontos, pelaos.... son considerados al llegar al cuartel.

---

[image]

*Panfleto pana niños en el que se cuenta la vida de Juan Soldado. Fechado entre 1880 y 1950.*

---

**Cancion divertida de la vida de Juan Soldado para cantar los aficionados**.

```
                                       La vida de Juan Soldado
                                       es muy larga de contar:
                                       que tender, que tender,
                                       que lavar, que lavar,
                                       que tender la ropa
                                       en el retamar. 

                                       Un soldado se ha perdido;
                                       lo salieron a buscar
                                       veinticinco granaderos
                                       un cabo y un oficial. 

                                       Que tender, que tender,
                                       que lavar, que lavar,
                                       que tender la ropa
                                       en el retamar
```

[image]

[image]

Publicación Fechada entre 1847. En la Imprenta y Librería de Juan Bautista Vidal. Reus

---

La cuestión "Juan Soldado" como apodo no seria difícil de adivinar, podría ser un soldado peculiar que recibe ese nombre y que por extensión nombra a los demás.

En este caso ese "Juan" no recoge solo su nombre, sino como "Juan Soldado", en su carácter militar, como se desprende de las distintas historias, recolecta toda una serie de "dichas y desdichas" que acontecen a su vida diaria. Esta exhibición cercana de durezas de la vida, invita a los lectores y a otros militares a participar de la misma narración. Una vida que maneja los distintos elementos de vicisitud, aventura o encuentros circunstanciales con ciertas realidades a veces mundanas, otras mágicas.

A "Juan Soldado" podemos encontrarle en una alistamiento por propia iniciativa, "bandera", en el que relata algunos aspectos de su bisoñez o la difícil relación con otros reclutas o mandos.

También el alistamiento puede ser forzoso, en el que se denuncia una especie de engaño, donde aquellos que reclutan, cabos o sargentos, y que llevan comisión, tratan de atraer a los mozos con espejismos y promesas de ascensos, condecoraciones, sueldos, galanterías ... que con ellos tratan de convencer al "pobre Juan", "Juan Soldado", al pobre soldado.

Igualmente los relatos pueden referirse a una batalla, guerra pasada, una historia lejana..., en el que relata la miseria, los latigazos, la injusticia, los demonios y la magia o el encuentro con la narración de su propia muerte.

---

[image]

*Luis de Eguílaz La vida de Juan Soldado, 1856*.

---

P.D. Existen muchas más obras, como la de Antonio de Trueba, «Vida de Juan Soldado» en el libro de los cantares, publicado en 1851, y más personas que han utilizado este apodo de "Juan Soldado", sin embargo, lo importante era el estudio del nombre de "Juan" con el alias de "Juan Soldado", su vinculación con el mundo castrense y el hecho de que su nombre aparezca entroncado de forma especial con el alistamiento, los reclutas los quintos y los soldados rasos en general, ya que un "Juan Soldado", podría ser tanto un quinto recién incorporado, un mercenario, alguien anciano o de cierta edad con una narración retrospectiva y lejana de una historia, un simple civil que se incorpora al ejercito en extrañas circunstancias, un licenciado, un reenganchado ... pero siempre visto desde la perspectiva de un soldado que pertenece habitualmente al escalafón más bajo del ejercito.

Aparte queda el empleo que hacen algunas personas del término "Juan Soldado", como pseudónimo. En estos casos, la interpretación que se hace puede ser para honrar al propio soldado, o para referirse al sentido lato del mundo militar del concepto "soldado", en su acepción general de obra, vida y lucha, en el que no se tiene en cuenta, de manera especial, el escalafón o grado militar y con el que se quiere expresar solo el sentimiento de pertenencia o apoyo a la institución. Espero haya resuelto dudas.

---

Resumen

- "Juan Bautista" Se dice de aquel que se dedicó a sumergir o verter agua sobre una persona, como símbolo de purificación y nacimiento a una nueva vida.
- "Juan Sin Miedo" Se dice de la persona que no teme al peligro o a las adversidades, un Juan sin miedo, un valiente.
- "Juan Soldado" Se dice de aquella persona que por lo general es o fue soldado raso. Referido a un soldado cualquiera.

---

Comment: Ya conocía está historia, y por supuesto que había leído el artículo. Pero no tiene nada que ver con esto, ya que ---como tú mismo puedes comprobar--- la acepción de **juan** como soldado ya aparece en el Diccionario de la lengua de 1925, y está historia es posterior (1938).

Comment: Las respuestas citando un enlace sin colocar al menos una parte relevante del contenido, es preferible colocarlas como comentario.

Comment: La verdad es que tu investigación es impresionante, y me va a dar pie a un montón de lectura. Pero... yo creo que seguimos sin ver el origen del sinónimo de "juan" como "soldado". Porque lo que tú aportas es **Juan Soldado**, y si "juan" es igual a "soldado", entonces sería lo mismo que decir "soldado soldado", ¿no? 
En cualquier caso, felicidades por la investigación, que es una maravilla.

Comment: No, "Juan" solo sirve de nombre tipo sobre el que se añaden los "alias", "Juan Tonto", "Juan Miserias", "Juan Cobarde". "Juan Mentiras". En el caso de "Juan Soldado", este se encuentra relacionado con los cadetes, reclutas o soldados rasos del ejercito. Así "Juan Soldado", es como si dijeras "Juan Pelao", "Juan Recluta", "Juan el quinto", "Juan Quinto" "Juan el soldado raso", "Juan el raso", "Juan Recluta" o "Juan enganchao" (de enganche/enganchado) . "Juan por otras razones más complejas, desde mi punto de vista, vendría de una forma del latín hispano para Jouen, Joven. Pero ese es otro tema.

Comment: Para expresarlo de otra manera, si llamamos a "Juan el Bautista" o "Juan Bautista" a alguien que se dedica a bautizar o esta conectado con ese acto de bautizar, de la misma forma decimos "Juan Soldado", para aquellos soldados que son cadetes, reclutas, bisoños o simples soldados rasos.